# Is there any option to achieve instant app through Flutter Development?

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

Does flutter support instant app?
If support can you share any reference links here.
I'm trying to creating instant app through the Flutter. But there's no official documents but we have that in iOS for app clips. So please someone help me to understand that Flutter does support instant app or not...

Thanks you

Flutter support instant app or not

Comment: requesting for libraries and or implementations is off topic for StackOverFlow. You can read the official Flutter documentation which is searchable on Google: https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/ios/ios-app-clip